# passing value to SQL command parameters error

Tags: asp.net

Is anyone can tell me, why I'm getting error here. 
If pass a value to parameters with this line 
int qID = 10087;

It works fine, but when I try this line 
int qID =  Int32.Parse(corr[0]);

It gives me error (failed), rest of code is same in both situations. What could be a problem here?

```
int pID1 = 102;
//int qID = 10087;
int qID =  Int32.Parse(corr[0]);
using (var cn1 = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lConn"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        cn1.Open();
                        string sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT Q FROM QATXT WHERE S= @pID AND QID=@qID ";
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, cn1);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pID", pID1);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qID", qID);
                        SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                        if (rdr1.Read())
                        {
                            mainQTxt = (string)rdr1.GetValue(0);
                        }

                        cn1.Close(); rdr1.Close(); cmd1.Dispose();
                    }//- End of cn


                    rep = mainQTxt ;
```

Comment: What is the exact error? It seems corr[0] is not a valid Integer

Comment: Error is failed, actually I'm working with AJAX,

Comment: corr[0] is a type of string and I'm converting this into int..

Comment: Even it's work, if do like this <br/>

Comment: make an alert(corr[0]) or something like that, it should give an integer value... If you had a valid number there (surrounded by " because of being a string) it wouldn't give error

Comment: string pID1 = "102";
string qID = "10087";

Comment: I alert the reponse, which is a valid number (10087) but of type string, but it's not working.

Comment: tried it at my end..it is working fine.The only reason can be the invalid string value in corr[0] which cannot be converted to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Changing `int qID = Int32.Parse(corr[0]);` to `int qID = Convert.ToInt32(corr[0]);`

Comment: Same error. Do you have idea, why it works, even when I try this: int qID = 10087;  OR  string qID = "10087";    Its working with both ways..

Comment: Because those are valid integers... definitely, you don't have a valid integer in 'corr[0]'

Comment: what's the value of corr[0]? @MrLearner

Comment: I run this command: return corr[0].Length + ":" + corr[0] +":" +  corr[1].Length + ":" + corr[1];    and get this:   5:10087:5:10092

Comment: Ok so what exactly are you trying to achieve here? i thought you wanted to convert string to int32? @MrLearner

Comment: corr[0] contains a question's ID and I'm trying to get Question's text from database by giving corr[0] in cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qID", qID); but this is not working..

Comment: /me confused... you mention Ajax but in your post there is only code behind (which you can debug and see exactly where it breaks and with which value for corr[0])...

Comment: AJAX is only passing a single id, then I get results from database and then proceed with these reults. Anyhow, problem is solved. Acutally I was putting <br/> along with value, which couldn't see in test View. Now it fixed. Thanks everyone for help..